# iOS - Remove .docc files before running CI pipeline from Swift Packages

Tags: swift, xcode, azure-devops, continuous-integration, swift-package-manager

I am trying to run my project using Azure CI but it is always failing because `Firebase` and `Pulse` two libraries that I have used in my Swift Package are using `.docc` extension files are causing issues and it always fails saying these folders cannot be open.

```
"Cannot open "Pulse.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".
```

And I am getting same error for Firebase as well. Is there a way to remove these files.

I tried to use this script on CI to remove it, but couldn't do so.

```
 - task: Bash@3
      displayName: "Remove .docc files"
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        sourceFolder: '/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/'
        script: |
          pwd
          echo $(pwd)
          ls -la
          echo "Delete following *.docc files:"
          echo $(find . -name "*.docc")
          find ./ -type d -name "*.docc" -exec rm -rf {} \;
          echo "remaining *.docc files:"
          echo $(find . -name "*.docc")
          cd /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
          ls -la
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual cause of the build failure? That error should not be failing builds, when you see that in the logs that's usually just masking the real build error.

Comment: How can I determine this? Locally it works and do not gives any error. @DávidPásztor

Comment: Hi Najam, if you want to remove .docc files, you can use devops task `DeleteFiles` instead of bash script, which is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove .docc files before running pipeline, you can use `DeleteFiles@1` task as a workaround.

```
- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Remove .docc files'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder:'/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/'
    contents: |
      *.docc
```

By the way, if you use `Xcode` task to build your app, please check the version you specify and keep it the same with your local version and run again to see if the issue persists.

Doc Referred:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/delete-files-v1?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops